# Undefined variable: id (GET)

Tags: php

Undefined variable: id, i tested the id by eachoing it and it worked so how it's Undefined

mycontroller

```
 if(isset($_GET['deleteid']))
    {
        $id  = $_GET['deleteid'];
        require_once '../model/dsections.php';
        $delete = new Dsections("sections");
        $delete->deletesec($id);
        require_once '../view/vsections.php';



}
```

model

```
class Dsections extends cone{

protected $tablename;


public function __construct($tablename)
{

    //DB table name.
    $this->tablename = $tablename;
    //DB connection.
    $this->connectTodb();
    //Delete function
    $this->deletesec($id);

}
public function deletesec($id)
{
    // Delete a specific section.
    $query = "DELETE * FROM $this->tablename WHERE id = $id ";

    if (!$sqli = mysqli_query($this->cxn->connect(),$query)) {


        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");

    }
}
```

}
the error at this line in mymodel
$this->deletesec($id);

Comment: can you please post the model/dsections.php?

Comment: one more thing did you try echoing `$id` both before and after `require_once '../model/dsections.php';` ?

Comment: i've just did it now and it eachoed before and after

Comment: get rid of $this->deletesec($id); in constructor

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Dsection` constructor you call `$this->deletesec($id);` on $id which is undefined :)

```
  public function __construct($tablename)
  {

      //DB table name.
      $this->tablename = $tablename;
      //DB connection.
      $this->connectTodb();
      //Delete function
      $this->deletesec($id); // <--------- this line here $id is not defined here

  }
```

The constructor must look like:

```
  public function __construct($tablename)
  {

      //DB table name.
      $this->tablename = $tablename;
      //DB connection.
      $this->connectTodb();
  }
```

Without delete function because you are calling it anyway later!

**OR** you can simply add the `$id` to the constructor like this:

```
  public function __construct($tablename,$id)
  {
      //DB table name.
      $this->tablename = $tablename;
      //DB connection.
      $this->connectTodb();
      //Delete function
      $this->deletesec($id);
  }
```

**BUT** this is not recommended, because it violates the most important software engineering principle (IMHO) which is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: when i remove $id it gives me 2 errors                                                        Missing argument 1 for Dsections::deletesec(), and Undefined variable: id in db query

Comment: You are correct but he is trying to call it directly not from the constructor.
`$delete = new Dsections("sections");
 $delete->deletesec($id);`

Comment: dont remove $id ... you must remove the whole line, since you are calling it in the main file !

Comment: yeah i got it and th error disappear but i got Error Processing Request which from the exception and i'm sorry i'm a new oop

Comment: Can you please +1 and accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

First try to either convert/cast your `$id = (int) $_GET['deleteid']; /* or */ $id = intval($_GET['deleteid'];` to an integer or surround it in single quotes `'$id'` in your SQL query.

NOTE: You can use type-hinting in your `deletesec` signature to always get a true value but not for scalar types in PHP < 7.